# Problem in taking screenshot from embedded youtube video by using CORS proxy

Tags: video, proxy, youtube, screenshot, youtube-dl

I have a website that has embedded youtube videos in iframes. What I want to achieve is let the users take screenshots from the videos. I understand that this is not possible because of the iframe, so I tried to find a way to load it in video tag. And I did it by taking the direct link of the video with the youtube-dl --get-url command. Then I used canvas to take the screenshot but when trying to save it as image I have a cors problem that tried to solve it with cors proxy. Below you can see what I have done until now.

I am doing

```
youtube-dl.exe --youtube-skip-dash-manifest -g "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVPYIRF9RCQ&ab_channel=AndyMatthewsAndyMatthews"
```

to take the direct link to the video.

result:

https://r4---sn-4vguioxu-5ui6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1623705253&ei=RXLHYKHILpqJ6dsPibuWqAk&ip=46.246.235.105&id=o-AFblFVsQOZ9iGvOmswv01H9c5K9EgPmwnQhLcazJjtNA&itag=137&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C137%2C160%2C242%2C243%2C244%2C247%2C248%2C278%2C394%2C395%2C396%2C397%2C398%2C399&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=6p&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-4vguioxu-5ui6%2Csn-4g5edns7&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=21&initcwndbps=643750&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&ns=_Qxaf9MVRRte_IA3zASupsUF&gir=yes&clen=20144050&dur=81.164&lmt=1606516531202697&mt=1623682853&fvip=4&keepalive=yes&fexp=24001373%2C24007246&c=WEB&txp=5432432&n=gdJX2QLyx7AIVJo21S-&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRgIhAIfncBiAbKNx_L81swFvTjRKFM-A6dd03OVkJRHMz9JKAiEAhLm7viW6ivpoPWiFZ6ZiS-PH-nYYClU6sqz97hTKBis%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIgaqK1EfsLf3kJVBvtfrAkk5UzqHCR-1TczhLStJPsFxsCIQCyuJ6vYiJiqUQoAJs0c_FsSHJZBOEVgUVZltkbYoDGHQ%3D%3D

Then this URL can be added to HTML video-tag and it works.
Then I am drawing the video into a canvas element in order to take a screenshot.

Until here everything works as expected.

Now I am trying to save the canvas as an image with

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasPostcard");
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

but there is a cors issue.
I add crossorigin="anonymous" inside the video tag but then the video does not play at all.

Then I used a cors proxy server in order to bypass this problem.
I created in a worker in cloudflare and run it locally like this

http://127.0.0.1:8787/?url=https://r4---sn-4vguioxu-5ui6.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1623705253&ei=RXLHYKHILpqJ6dsPibuWqAk&ip=46.246.235.105&id=o-AFblFVsQOZ9iGvOmswv01H9c5K9EgPmwnQhLcazJjtNA&itag=137&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C137%2C160%2C242%2C243%2C244%2C247%2C248%2C278%2C394%2C395%2C396%2C397%2C398%2C399&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&mh=6p&mm=31%2C29&mn=sn-4vguioxu-5ui6%2Csn-4g5edns7&ms=au%2Crdu&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=21&initcwndbps=643750&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fmp4&ns=_Qxaf9MVRRte_IA3zASupsUF&gir=yes&clen=20144050&dur=81.164&lmt=1606516531202697&mt=1623682853&fvip=4&keepalive=yes&fexp=24001373%2C24007246&c=WEB&txp=5432432&n=gdJX2QLyx7AIVJo21S-&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRgIhAIfncBiAbKNx_L81swFvTjRKFM-A6dd03OVkJRHMz9JKAiEAhLm7viW6ivpoPWiFZ6ZiS-PH-nYYClU6sqz97hTKBis%3D&lsparams=mh%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cmvi%2Cpl%2Cinitcwndbps&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIgaqK1EfsLf3kJVBvtfrAkk5UzqHCR-1TczhLStJPsFxsCIQCyuJ6vYiJiqUQoAJs0c_FsSHJZBOEVgUVZltkbYoDGHQ%3D%3D

But I am taking a Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

If I use another URL for example http://127.0.0.1:8787/?url=https://in.gr
it works without error.

Do you know what maybe is the problem here?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I am able to bypass it temporarily using this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en

But I also need a permanent solution. Let me know if you find something

Comment: @BilalKhan Exactly, my other approach was server-side to use FFmpeg with youtube-dl to take the screenshot like this ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05.00 -i "your-url-here" -frames:v 1 -q:v 2 "localpath-output.jpg" but it's not for me a viable solution as it consumes more memory and it's too much for just a screenshot.